# Mini-Page Layout inside Pageblocktable

Tags: pageblocktable

I have inscribed pageblocktable inside Outputpanel so that I can have records and scroll bar when we have records to scroll.

I used account records in pageblocktable. For each account record,I managed to show Mini-page Layout when we hover in Account Name Link.

The problem comes here, When I hover a record in pageblocktable, I could see mini pagelayout pops-up. But when I scroll and try to hover, The page size increasing. Initially I thought,It was problem with Mini-page Layout.

Today I managed to Show Custom pop-up. Still problem persisted and got confirmed that It was not problem with Mini-Page Layout.

Now I stuck Of How to reduce this problem.

Might be I need to add some functionality.

For getting hover I used

```
<apex:column headerValue="Account Name" headerClass="TableTitle">
    <a href="/{!doc.acc.Id}" 
       id="{!doc.acc.Id}" 
       position="relative"
       onblur="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!doc.acc.Id}').hide();" 
       onfocus="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!doc.acc.Id}', '/{!doc.acc.Id}/m?retURL=%2F{!doc.acc.Id}&isAjaxRequest=1').show();" 
       onmouseout="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!doc.acc.Id}').hide();" 
       onmouseover="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!doc.acc.Id}', '/{!doc.acc.Id}/m?retURL=%2F{!doc.acc.Id}&isAjaxRequest=1').show();">
{!doc.acc.name}
</a>
</apex:column>
```

Please Help me..!!

Comment: What do you mean with `The page size increasing`? Width/height`? Post your visualforce page code.

Comment: Could you add an screenshot in order to clarify ?

Answer (score 0):

did you tried fixing the height of the output panel? Set the layout of the outputPanel to block and use css to fix the height of the output panel.

Comment: I tried to fix the height of Output panel.But could get the result

Answer (score 0):

Not sure with the mini page layout hack, but if you're using custom popup onhover, you need to consider the page scroll offset, and write some JavaScript/JQuery code in order to position your popup correctly.